# Logstash/Elasticsearch CSV Field Types, Date Formats and Multifields (.raw)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've been playing around with getting a tab delimited file into Elasticsearch using the CSV filter in Logstash. Getting the data in was actually incredibly easy, but I'm having trouble getting the field types to come in right when I look at the data in Kibana. Dates and integers continue to come in as strings, so I can't plot by date or do any analysis functions on integers (sum, mean, etc).

I'm also having trouble getting the .raw version of the fields to populate. For example, in device I have data like "HTC One", but when if I do a pie chart in Kibana, it'll show up as two separate groupings "HTC" and "One". When I try to chart device.raw instead, it comes up as a missing field. From what I've read, it seems like Logstash should automatically create a raw version of each string field, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

I've been sifting through the documentation, google and stack, but haven't found a solution. Any ideas appreciated! Thanks.

Config file:

```
#logstash.conf
input {  
      file {
          path => "file.txt"
          type => "event"
          start_position => "beginning"
          sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
}

filter {  
    csv {
      columns => ["userid","date","distance","device"]
      separator => "    "
    }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        port => "9200"
        protocol => "http"
        index => "userid" 
        workers => 2
        template => template.json

    }
    #stdout {
    #    codec => rubydebug
    #}
}
```

Here's the template file:

```
#template.json:
{
    "template": "event",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "index" : {
            "query" : { "default_field" : "userid" } 
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": { 
            "_all": { "enabled": false },
            "_source": { "compress": true },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_template" : { 
                        "match" : "*",
                        "mapping": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
                     } 
                 }
             ],
             "properties" : {
                "date" : { "type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
                "device" : { "type" : "string", "fields": {"raw": {"type":  "string","index": "not_analyzed"}}},
                "distance" : { "type" : "integer"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - the template name IS the index. So the "template" : "event" line should have been "template" : "userid"

Comment: The "template" attribute at the root of your template is actually a pattern, so "user*" would match any indices starting with the word "user".  The name of the template is given when you POST it into elasticsearch.  The doc:  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: @econgineer I also (unsuccessfully) tried to cast the columns of the csv filter to certain types e.g. instead of string to an integer. Did you have any luck with that as well?

Comment: @markus, like I said, the above worked once I made sure the "template" attribute was labeled the same as the index name that I defined in the logstash.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I found another (easier) way to specify the type of the fields. You can use logstash's mutate filter to change the type of a field. Simply add the following filter after your csv filter to your logstash config

```
  mutate {
    convert => [ "fieldname", "integer" ]
  }
```

For details check out the [logstash docs - mutate convert](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#convert)

Comment: There is also a "convert" attribute of the csv filter, but it didn't work for me. Any thoughts why, @markus?

Comment: @DmitriLikhachev sorry but I haven't used that yet.